# How to optimize a matrix 3 by 3 multiplication with a point with SSE?

Tags: c++, optimization, sse, matrix-multiplication

I have to apply a transformation matrix in each point of my image to get the new point coordinate.

To do that, I created a custom `Matrix3by3` class which contains a array of size 9 of floats.

To apply the matrix to each point, first I created this function:

```
constexpr auto apply_matrix(const Matrix3by3 & m, const Vec2i & p) -> Vec2f
{
  const auto x = m.at(0, 0) * p.x + m.at(0, 1) * p.y + m.at(0, 2);
  const auto y = m.at(1, 0) * p.x + m.at(1, 1) * p.y + m.at(1, 2);
  const auto z = m.at(2, 0) * p.x + m.at(2, 1) * p.y + m.at(2, 2);

  return { x / z, y / z };
}
```

As you can see, this function will do simple matrix multiplication without the last multiplication since there is no z value in my 2D images.

This works great, but since this part of the code is hot code, I'm trying to optimize it, so I created a SSE version of it:

```
constexpr auto apply_matrix(const Matrix3by3 & m, const Vec2i & p) -> Vec2f
{
  using SSEVec3 = union {
    struct
    {
      float z, y, x;

    };
    __m128 values_ = _mm_setzero_ps();
  };

  const auto mvec1 = _mm_set_ps(0, m.at(0, 0), m.at(0, 1), m.at(0, 2));
  const auto mvec2 = _mm_set_ps(0, m.at(1, 0), m.at(1, 1), m.at(1, 2));
  const auto mvec3 = _mm_set_ps(0, m.at(2, 0), m.at(2, 1), m.at(2, 2));

  const auto pvec1 = _mm_set1_ps(static_cast<float>(p.x));
  const auto pvec2 = _mm_set1_ps(static_cast<float>(p.y));

  auto result = SSEVec3{};
  result.values_ = _mm_add_ps(_mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(mvec1, pvec1), _mm_mul_ps(mvec2, pvec2)), mvec3);

  return { result.x / result.z, result.y / result.z };
}
```

This works too, but it is slower than the first version, and since I'm in the process of learning SSE, I cannot see exactly why this is the case.

My idea with this second version was to do the x, y, and z value calculation in parallel.

So, that's my question, why the SSE version is slower and how can I optimize it to be as fast as possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Whenever optimizing at this level, you should be inspecting the generated assembly code: `gcc -S`. Can you make your code more complete: what does the surrounding code look like? What times did you get from your runs? Also, I'd avoid declaring functions `constexpr` when trying to compare their performance.

Comment: I would expect this to possibly be dominated by that final division by z. In any case, you should really look at the disassembly output for your obvious version first. Considering the modern C++ style, you are probably using a pretty recent compiler where auto-vectorization just might be turned on.

Depending on what chip you have, the manual store using mm_set_ps and m.at will also kill you. SSE doesn't have "gather" instructions, so do an unaligned load and then mask out the lowest word or just ignore the results.

Comment: Abusing `_mm_set_ps` that way is a major anti pattern, that should really be a proper wide load (which will load one lane too much, pad if necessary).

Comment: Have you tried to compare the performance with and without SIMD enabled compiler optimization? This will tell you if the compiler is already using SIMD, just as looking through the assembly would. Either way, you should pad your array in your matrix and use load as suggested by @harold .

Comment: Does "each point of my image" literally mean `{(0,0), (0,1), ..., (0,width-1), (1, 0), ..., (height-1, width-1)}`? Or just a larger set of "interesting" points? And I assume the matrix stays the same for all points?

Comment: @Sassa: Did you get my questions? Without context it is hard to tell how to optimize your function (at least show the main loop which calls your `apply_matrix` method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, **optimize only what needs optimizing**, not what you guess needs it.

Probably the single worst point in the (original) code, and your 'optimizations' didn't help it at all, is the duplicate *division*. Dividing floats or doubles is by far worse than everything else in this code, so your best optimization is to reduce it by calculating 1/z (dividing *once*) into a helper variable, and then multiplying two times with the result.

But - as said in the beginning - you might not need any optimizing, or you might need others. Test, profile, and look for the slowest piece of coding. Guessing results typically in wasted effort and unnecessary code complexity.

Comment: Of course since we're doing SSE anyway, those two divisions can be arranged to be done in the same instruction, which may be nicer than multiplying by the reciprocal (unless the approx. recip. is used)